# Why does my filter not work when i add intergers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to show and hide elements from an array. The entire filter works well except with the numbers. When I use this filter that item.sprint === does not grab `this.state.currentSprint` and just displays both:

```
{
  this.state.personalItems
  .filter(
    item => item.user == this.state.user 
    || item.public == "true" 
    && item.sprint === this.state.currentSprint
  )
  .map((l, i) => ())
}
```

This variable corresponds to 1 === 2 as in the following example:

```
{
  this.state.personalItems
    .filter(
      item => item.user == this.state.user 
      || item.public == "true" 
      && 1 === 2
    )
    .map((l, i) => ())
}
```

I have already checked if they are integers etc. does anyone have the solution where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check [`operator precedence for && and ||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). In your code it will evaluate condition as below.

```
item => item.user == this.state.user 
    || (item.public == "true" && item.sprint === this.state.currentSprint)
```

You should use wrap `||` condition with `()` and update condition as below.

```
{
  this.state.personalItems
  .filter(
    item => (item.user == this.state.user || item.public == "true")
            && item.sprint === this.state.currentSprint
  )
  .map((l, i) => ())
}
```